# remove multiple style tags using regular expression in C#

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

I have the following html source which consists of two style tags, using regular expressions we are able to remove all the html tags from the file,but the we are not able to remove the content of second style tag

```
<style id="owaParaStyle" type="text/css">P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;}</style>
```

C# Code

```
1) Regex test = new Regex(@"<[^\>]*>{}");
2) strText = test.Replace(strText, String.Empty);
```

Output:-

```
1) Expected is blank but we get P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but i want the attributes/values of style tag also to be removed

You can try with [**back reference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) that matches the same text as previously matched by a capturing group.

To remove everything inside the `<...>` to `</...>` use below regex that looks for **same** opening and closing HTML tags.

```
                   <(\w+)[^>]*>.*<\/\1>
Captured Group 1-----^^^             ^^----- Back Reference first matched group
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rZ7lQ2/4)

Comment: This helps in removing all the style tags from the file.but i want the attributes/values of style tag also to be removed.<style id="owaParaStyle" type="text/css">P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;}</style>

Comment: Have you tested it at your end? It does remove. Look in demo.

Comment: even in demo its leaving behind "P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;}". even this has to be removed.

Comment: so you want to replace everything inside the html style tags? Let me update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove the style tag?

```
<style.*?</style>
```

I would not generally recommend using regex to match HTML/XML unless you are sure that it always has a certain structure. There is better tools for manipulating XML.